# How to get the start time of the previous month in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, time

I'd like to get the "start" time (the time right at the beginning of the month), of the previous month relative to the current time.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `UTCTime` we can define a function:

```
import Data.Time

getStartOfPreviousMonth :: UTCTime -> UTCTime 
getStartOfPreviousMonth v = do
  let (y,m,_) = (toGregorian $ utctDay v)
  let v' = addGregorianMonthsClip (-1) $ fromGregorian y m 1
  v { utctDay = v'
    , utctDayTime = secondsToDiffTime 0
    }
```

Which can be used like so:

```
> import Data.Time
Data.Time> ct <- getCurrentTime
Data.Time> getStartOfPreviousMonth ct
2020-07-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: You can't use `do` here, your result type has the wrong shape.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Have you asked the compiler whether it agrees with your assessment? I think you should.

Comment: This `do` expression simply desugars to a `let` expression like `let (y, m, _) = ... in let v' = ... in v {...}`.

Comment: Even though you can use `do` this way, I think it should be discouraged.  It's likely to cause confusion (and already has, for at least two of us).